# How to print both key-value pairs in this Swift for-in example

Tags: swift

This example is from Apple's "[A Swift Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#)" section demonstrating for-in.

Super newbie question, but how come it's not printing the `type` variable too? Is it something to do with the scope?

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
var largest = 0
var type: String
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            type = kind
        }
    }
}
largest
type
```

Comment: can you be more specific on this ? if this is your code it should print out. (type is inferred from values in dictionary and you dont have to explicitly make it assigned to "" )  
`$R1: Int = 25` 
`$R2: Int = "Square"`

Comment: @nsuinteger I thought it would print out too for the same reason but it didn't print anything in the GuidedTour.playground file until I followed connor's answer to explicitly initialize to empty string.

Comment: The problem is that a variable of type `String` cannot be nil.  It must be assigned to some value.  You can either use the type `String?` instead of `String`, or you can initialize `type` to an empty string as Connor suggests.

Comment: @epan its weird because it prints out that in console for me... I checked it out my self (without any initialization). anyways since you already have the answer by Connor I guess no point extending the conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `type` to an empty string first like this:

```
var type: String = ""
```

Comment: Wow thanks! You answered so quickly that I must wait to accept it.

Comment: This is correct, as `String` will default to a `nil` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]

var largest = 0
var type : String = ""


for (kind , numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for num in numbers{
        if num>largest{
            largest=num
            type=kind
        }
    }
} 
println(largest,type)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var items: [(String, String)] = [
        ("Working life balance", "work_life_balance_icon.png"),
        ("Cutting Down on Alcohol", "cutting_down_alcohol_icon.png"),
        ("Smoking Cessation","smoking_cessation_icon.png"),
        ("Eating a healthy diet","eating_healthy_diet_icon.png"),
        ("Exercise", "exercise_icon.png"),
        ("Loosing Weight","loosing_weight_icon"),
        ("Heart Disease Risk Tracker", "qrisk.png"),
        ("BMI Tracker", "bmi.png")
    ]

println("value \(items[0])")
```